# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 DB Backup script

Tags: backup, sql-server-2012, database-backup

I have **SQL Server Management Studio 2012** installed on a **VM**. We have an active DB (attached to an ASP.Net application whose target Framework is 4.0). What I was looking for is a **script to backup a DB** that I can attach to Task Scheduler to take backup once a day and copy that backup file to my local machine.

As far as copying of file is concerned I can do that using Robocopy, but I am yet to create a script to automatically take backup. I read a few articles but they were too outdated (SQL Server 2000).

I also checked this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/930615 But Step 8 in this link becomes invalid as **"Script Action to Job"** is disabled.

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: Is this SQL Express?

Comment: I can't see SQL Express installed on my machine. I have opted for database authentication mode while connecting to my db